# best way to compile a perl script for macintosh? (os x)

Tags: perl

I see that on stack overflow, there is discussion about compiling perl for Unix and Windows machines that don't have a perl interpreter installed.

i.e. [Compiling a perl script to a .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278652/compiling-a-perl-script-to-a-exe)

I'm wondering what to do for Mac? Would I need to compile it and make it run on my own OSX system before I send it to someone else? Is perl just the wrong language for this in general?

Comment: What do you mean, "what to do for Mac"? OS X ships with a Perl interpreter already installed, so you shouldn't have this use-case there.

Comment: well, that may be true, but OS X does NOT necessarily ship with CPAN or any of the libraries that the script could require. Just because perl is there, doesn't mean that the script will work. Also, older versions of perl might not run a newer script (if the OSX installation is old, which can be common with macintosh, as often people will keep their old macintosh hardware and never upgrade the operating system).

Comment: use [pp](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.014/lib/pp.pm) just like on unix machine, which packaged all required CPAN modules and perl interpreter into an executable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm use [Perl Dev Kit (PDK)](http://www.activestate.com/perl-dev-kit) for this. It's not free but with PerlApp tool I can create executables for many platforms.